# MySQL COUNT with group by or distinct

Tags: mysql

I have the table "objects":

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
group_id (varchar) default null
```

I do some inserts:

```
insert into objects values
(null, 'Cat', null),
(null, 'Dog', null),
(null, 'Mouse', 'AAA'),
(null, 'Eagle', 'BBB'),
(null, 'Elephant', null),
(null, ' Bull', 'AAA');
```

I need to count the total number of rows. However, the two rows where the group_id is "AAA" should merge to a single row.
In the example above "count" should return "5". This is because:

- There are 3 rows with NULL value for the field "group_id"
- There is 1 "occurence" of rows with group_id "BBB"
- There is 1 "occurence" of rows with group_id "AAA"

Doing a count with group_id doesnt seem to be the solution, as it returns 3 rows, and for each row it gives a count. I only need the total count of rows.

Using DISTINCT doesnt seem to help either. The query:

```
select count(distinct(group_id)) from objects;
```

returns a row with the value "2"

Comment: how id can be null? that should not be null

Comment: @bluto it's an auto incrementing integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE Group by with condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM objects 
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN group_id IS NULL THEN id
    ELSE group_id
    END
```

Comment: but this will not return 5

Comment: did you test this? it simply does not match the requested result - `I only need the total count of rows.` and `In the example above "count" should return "5". `

Comment: would you please explain why this is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

COUNT() only increments for NON_NULL values, so

```
select count(distinct IFNULL(group_id,'-9nTfx')) from objects;
```

will return 3 from your sample data being 1 each for 'AAA' 'BBB' and NULL.

You are asking for a result of 5, so I suggest this:

```
select
  count(distinct group_id) 
  + count(case when group_id IS NULL then 1 end) 
from objects;
```

- Please note that DISTINCT is NOT a function, so when you write
  DISTINCT(group_id) those parentheses are simply ignored. This is also
  true of "select distinct(somecolumn)" by the way.

@used_by_already explained well. i just done this demo given blow

[SEE WORKING DEMO IN ACTION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d0617/17)

Answer (score 0):

This second answer exists as a test result for consideration.

[This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aa0e/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM objects 
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN group_id IS NULL THEN id
    ELSE group_id
    END
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aa0e/2/1)**:

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
```